# Start Chrome in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I did an youtube bot and I`m trying to make it work on a server 24/7 with ubuntu, I`m getting an error everytime, I already tried all solutions from the internet and got nowhere here is the error
I`m using google chrome stable at Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61 and chromedriver specified to it, so I really don`t even imagine what is wrong with this code right now, so I`m trying to figure it out but had no success

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newproxy.py", line 45, in <module>
    a = youtube_bot()
  File "newproxy.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=RC.chromedriver_path,options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

here is the code that its starting chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from RC import RC


class youtube_bot():

def __init__(self):

    options = Options()

    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    PROXY = "216.244.74.138:19006"
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "autodetect": False
    }
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=RC.chromedriver_path,options=options)
    self.driver.get(RC.youtube_link)

def open_youtube_video(self):
    time.sleep(20)
    #paste youtube inside of self.driver.get
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ytd-player/div/div/div[4]/button').click()
        print('Video running')
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(2)
    print("ok")
```

Comment: What happens if you try to start `/usr/bin/google-chrome` with the same arguments on the command line? Does it provide additional error output?

Comment: @jordanm I get this [22307:22307:0521/192246.414178:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Comment: Well, there you go. Don't run it as root.

Comment: @jordanm created another account and got the same error $ python3 newproxy.py
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Chrome/chromedriver'

Comment: That looks like a completely different error (permission denied vs process no longer running)

Comment: @jordanm nvm solved!!!, thanks man

Comment: solved giving permission to chromedriver

Comment: Np. good to hear.